# HTTP Client NoCache Flag Cause Null Reference Exception C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient, cache-control, pragma

I added this line to apply no caching in HTTP Client

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl.NoCache = true;
```

When i run the app which was working fine before, i get this exception in the second line:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried this was of applying the NoChache Flag which runs fine but i am not sure if it does what is expected.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
{ 
    DefaultRequestHeaders=
    { 
        CacheControl = CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache, no-store"),
        Pragma = { NameValueHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache")}
    }
};
```

Please help me apply the correct way to set the NoCache flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like when instantiating a new `HttpClient` it's `CacheControl` is set to `null`. Your solution is a way to set the `CacheControl` to not cache, but this is a less verbose way of doing it:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue {NoCache = true};
```

**Edit:** Corrected spelling errors

Comment: I will test and return back to you , but are you missing some parenthesis '(' this looks like visual basic

Comment: Or `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`